# TQuestion about testing rxjs observable with mergeMap and pipe

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs

Here probably very bad code..  If you can, can you help with writing better code
My main question is how to test this code. with pipe and mergeMap.
The jest always complains it can't test anything inside subscribe (result, error)
I did  spyOn(component, 'checkFriends').and.returnValues(of({MOCK_DATA}));

```
// array of people, could be better may be using rxjs from?
this.people?.map(person => {
  // this is apollo call to check friends with this person
  this.checkFriends(person)
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        mergeMap(() => this.updateFriendCircle())              
     )
    .subscribe((result) =>{
      // save counts of the invites
      result.invites ?? invite_counts ++;
      if(invite_counts === 100) 
        popular();      
    }, (error) => {
      logError();          
  })
});
```

Comment: You need to mock out your dependencies so you can create the data that would be returned that you can then test with.  Therefore, the people[] could be mocked to be a valid list as you expect them, or an error.  The inner handling can be mocked to test at that level.  The biggest issue you will have is creating the mock at what level to test.  You have a lot of combined logic in one area making it touch to test, as you can see from your question.  Potentially you could break up this code into smaller chunks of functionality, to better allow for testing and your mocks.

Comment: I meant to add that it is also best to show how you tried to test this, with your attempt, rather than just asking 'How To' do something.   See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for information on how to write a good question that is likely to get answered.